# How to make a button appear when a face is detected with camera2 API?

Tags: android, face-detection

I am developing a face detector with the camera2 API and I have to make the button "take picture" appear only if there is one face detected.

I am a student and this is my first try on Android Development.
I used the sample Android-camera2-api-face-recon in JAVA, the detection work, but now I have to make a button appear if a face is detected. I tried to put a condition in `process` like

`if(faces.lenght>0) {good condition=true}` but it don't work.

I expect my button appears when there is a face detected, have you some advises?

Comment: You may find an approach in this question. Check the callback method process(CaptureResult result) and how they're extracting info about faces.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435370/face-detection-draw-circle-using-android-camera2-api

Comment: I works thank you !